# ERROR Response with status: 401 OK for URL

Tags: angular, angular-fullstack

[Here is the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liXvw.png)
 I am trying to implement authGuard for my webste. But when I interfere with error codes, the app call back office and send  error.
Please help me!.

My AuthGuard.ts

```
public canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:     RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        // L'utilisateur est identifié, on accède à la page demandée
        if (Tools.isIE()) {
            this.router.navigate(['/redirect']);
            return false;
        } else {
            if (localStorage.getItem('currentUser')) {
                return true;
            }
                       this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, see good practices to ask an well received question [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: add routes file

Comment: What is the problem? It goes to 'localStorage.getItem('currentUser')' and it should not?

Comment: no it show this message  when i redirect  and it shouldnt because its call a back office 
ERROR Response with status: 401 OK for URL

Comment: @MehdiAli I have the same error. Did you manage to fix it? Also I'm fairly sure it has to do with your backend and not with your frontend. Maybe add the code where you do the HTTP call to the backend